# magento 2 state dropdown from custom table in address form

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, magento2.2.2

I want to show state drop-down in checkout address form.
state options will be come from my custom table. not from **`directory_country_region_name`**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**After lot of search finally i got solution:**

`Vendor/Module/registration.php` & put below code.

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

add the **module.xml** file in `Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml` & put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

add the **InstallSchema.php** file in `Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallSchema.php` &  put below code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface {
    /**
    * install table
    *
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaInterface $setup
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
    * @return void
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength) 
    * 
    */
    public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
            /*State Table */
              if (!$installer->tableExists('state')) {
                $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                    $installer->getTable('state')
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'state_id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' =>true,
                        'nullable' =>false,
                        'primary'  =>true,
                        'unsinged' =>true,
                    ],
                    'state Id'
                )

                ->addColumn(
                    'state_code',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    [ 'nullable =>false'],
                    'State Code'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'name',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    [ 'nullable =>false'],
                    'Name'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'country_code',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    [ 'nullable =>false'],
                    'Country Code'
                )
                ->setComment('state Table');

                $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
                $installer->getConnection()->addIndex(
                    $installer->getTable('state'),
                    $setup->getIdxName(
                        $installer->getTable('state'),
                        ['state_id','state_code','name','country_code'],
                        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                    ),
                    ['state_id','state_code','name','country_code'],
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                );

            }
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
}
```

In Block `Vendor/Module/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php` put below code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;

/**
 * Class LayoutProcessor
 * @package Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout
 */
class LayoutProcessor implements \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface
{

    /**
     * @var DirectoryHelper
     */
    protected $directoryHelper;

    /***
    * State Option
    *
    * @var Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Stateoptions
    */

    protected $_stateOption;    

    /**
     * LayoutProcessor constructor.
     * @param DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\Stateoptions $stateOptions
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Stateoptions $stateOption,
        DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper
    ) {
        $this->directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
        $this->_stateOption    = $stateOption;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $result
     * @return array
     */
    public function process($result)
    {

        if ($result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
        ['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']) 
        {

            $shippingAddressFieldSet = $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
            ['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];

            region = $this->_stateOption->getStates();  
            $regionOptions[] = ['label' => 'Please Select..', 'value' => ''];
             foreach ($region as $field) {
                    $regionOptions[] = ['label' => $field['name'], 'value' => $field['name']];
                }


            $shippingAddressFieldSet['region_id'] = '';
            $shippingAddressFieldSet['region'] = '';
            result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
            ['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'] = $shippingAddressFieldSet;
            $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
            ['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['region'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select', 
                    'id' => 'drop-down',
                    'additionalClasses' => 'state-drop-down',
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.region',
                'label' => 'Province',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 115,
                'id' => 'state-drop-down',
                'options' => $regionOptions
            ];

        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

In Model `Vendor/Module/Model/Source/Stateoptions.php` put below code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Source;

/**
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Stateoptions implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }

    /**
     * Options getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $optionArray = [];
         foreach ($this->getStates() as $field) {
            $options[] = ['label' => $field['name'], 'value' => $field['state_id']];
        }
        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [0 => __('No'), 1 => __('Yes')];
    }
    public function getStates()
    {
        $adapter = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $select = $adapter->select()
                    ->from('state');
        return $adapter->fetchAll($select);
    }
}
```

In etc `Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="vendor_area_layoutprocessor" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This will shows state drop down from custom table(state) in **shipping address form in checkout**